# How to Open link automatically in new tab without any manual action using java script or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have the below code in my HTML

the new tab is being blocked by the browser as a popup

```js
    <script>
        setTimeout(function () {
        location.href = "/user/agent/dashboard";
      }, 100);
    </script>

<script>
  function NewTab() { 
        window.open( 
          "{{ .destination }}", 1000);
        }
  NewTab();
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you believe that such action *should not* be taken be blocked?

Comment: *the new tab is being blocked by the browser as a popup* and thank goodness for that!

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
    location.href = "/user/agent/dashboard","window name","_blank";
  }, 100);
</script>
```

Comment: I need to open 2 links, one in the current tab and one in another tab...for one link there was no issue

Comment: location.href = "/user/agent/dashboard","window name","_blank"; location.href = "/user/agent/dashboard","window name","_self";